# Generalization bound on out of distribution data

Tags: bounds, out-of-sample, pac-learning

Assume we have two sets of data $X_1$ and $X_2$ drawn from two different distributions. Are the loss of the empirical risk minimizer of $X_1$ on $X_2$: $l_{X_2}(f_{X_1})$ the same as the loss of the empirical risk minimizer of $X_2$  on $X_1$: $l_{X_1}(f_{X_2})$ the same? If not, is there any existing result characterizing this out-of-distribution generalization bound?